# Saving JSON files in SSMS renders them unparsable?

Tags: ssms, json, parse

I have some query that outputs a JSON, i.e.,

```
select 1 AS 'test'
for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

After clicking on the result, which is {'test':1}, SSMS 18.10 opens a file with the JSON output. If I save this file as test.json, and attempt to load it elsewhere (either in an editor like Atom, in Python, etc), I get an error.

In comparison, if I copy the output and paste it into an empty test.json file, it works just fine.

What is going on here?

Comment: Try one more time with your sample; and I think it causes no error. It must be something with your actual code.

Comment: Just tried it again. Doesn't work. I can try to take a video. Did you try opening it in some language (i.e., json.load in Python) or pretty-printing it in an editor?

Comment: Open the saved file in a plain text editor. Is anything awry?

Comment: @MichaelGreen No. I checked for special characters and the like. Also used the tool CompareIt, and it found no differences. To fix the issue, all I need to do is copy the contents of the file into a newly created file. So weird.